Parse string column containing date with only month and year
For example:
import polars as pl

dates = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("date", ["2024,2", "2024,12"]))
dates = dates.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_date("%Y,%m"))

This does not work because of the missing day. Python's strptime adds a day of 1:
from time import strptime

strptime("2024,2", "%Y,%m")

Is there any way to do something similar with polars, apart from just attaching to the strings a day?
import polars as pl

dates = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("date", ["2024,2", "2024,12"]))
dates = dates.with_columns((pl.col("date") + ",1").str.to_date(r"%Y,%m,%d"))

Which is an okay solution, but it does unnecessary work. So the best solution I have come up with in terms of not doing repetitive work is:
import polars as pl

dates = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("date", ["2024,2", "2024,12"]))
dates = (
    dates.with_columns(
        pl.col("date").str.split(",").list.to_struct(fields=["year", "month"])
    )
    .unnest("date")
    .with_columns(date=pl.date(pl.col("year"), pl.col("month"), 1))
)


Going from a list to a struct requires copying the data and since strings are stored as stringview, it might be cheaper to just concat the string as in your first solution.
At the very least you can skip going through the struct and unnesting which is also unnecessary by using .list.get(). You can couple this with the walrus operator to keep it DRY.
dates = dates.with_columns(
    date=pl.date(
        (date_split := pl.col("date").str.split(",")).list.get(0),
        date_split.list.get(1),
        1,
    )
)

Alternatively, you could skip the list by using .str.split_exact which returns a struct upfront. If you do that, you can skip unnest with .struct[0] and .struct[1] as in
dates.with_columns(
    date=pl.date(
        (datestruct := pl.col("date").str.split_exact(",", 1)).struct[0],
        datestruct.struct[1],
        1,
    )
)

Performance
Setup
df=pl.DataFrame({'dates':pl.date_range(pl.date(1970,1,1), pl.date(2024,7,1), '1mo', eager=True)})
df=df.with_columns(pl.col('dates').dt.strftime("%Y,%m"))

String concat
%%timeit
df.with_columns((pl.col('dates')+",1").str.to_date(r"%Y,%m,%d"))
731 µs ± 6.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

through list
%%timeit
dates.with_columns(
    date=pl.date(
        (date_split := pl.col("date").str.split(",")).list.get(0),
        date_split.list.get(1),
        1,
    )
)
1.35 ms ± 6.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

through struct
%%timeit
dates.with_columns(
    date=pl.date(
        (datestruct := pl.col("date").str.split_exact(",", 1)).struct[0],
        datestruct.struct[1],
        1,
    )
)
1.29 ms ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

Conclusion
Using string concat is much faster than splitting the string and using a date constructor.

I think your workarounds are both valid since your data will need some extra cleaning/standardizing (and that's okay).
Here's another alternative that uses regex to pad months with zeros as needed:
import polars as pl
import re

def zero_pad(s):
    return re.sub(r",(\d)$", r",0\1", s) # pad number that come after a comma if it is only 1 digit

dates = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("date", map(zero_pad, ["2024,2", "2024,12"])))
dates = dates.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_date("%Y,%m"))

print(dates)


The issue isn't zero padding. The issue is that chrono (the datetime crate under the hood) insists on having the day part of the date.

@DeanMacGregor It does seem to work with the zero padding. (Although the cost of zero padding is "slower" than the str concat approach.)
